# Как запустить приложение в отдельном X сервере?

Tags: archlinux

Я наткнулся на [статью в вики](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Gaming_(%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9)) (Глава "Запуск игр в отдельном X сервере") о том, что игры можно запускать в отдельном X сервере. Якобы, это может незначительно, но улучшить производительность. Так вот, я хотел бы запустить нормально CS: GO, у меня там какраз 50 фпс, можно будет протестировать. Вот скрипт, который этим занимается:

```
#!/bin/sh
tmpgame="/tmp/game.sh"

cat <<EOT > ${tmpgame}
steam steam://run/730
EOT

xinit ${tmpgame} -- :1 vt$XDG_VTNR
```

Все бы хорошо, но, когда игра уже запустилась, не захватывается курсор. Насколько я понял, проблему может решить запуск оконного менеджера. Я попробовал несколько способов, у меня не получалось. Единственный вариант, когда оконный менеджер не выдавал ошибку при запуске, был:

```
...
gnome-shell --display-server &
steam steam://run/730 
...
```

Я подозреваю, что я неправильно запускаю этот оконный менеджер. Я его запускаю отдельно от игры, а нужно игру в нем запустить. Или я вообще не в ту сторону копаю. В общем, у кого есть какие идеи по данному поводу?

Answer (score 0):

Конечно игру нужно запустить именно в оконном менеджере. В качестве примера возьмем такой WM, как Openbox.
Скрипт запуска игры в Openbox, из вашего домашнего каталога или из /usr/local/bin, будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
$ cat ~/game.sh
if [ $# -ge 1 ]; then
  game="`which $1`"
  openbox="`which openbox`"
  tmpgame="/tmp/tmpgame.sh"
  DISPLAY=:1.0
  echo -e "${openbox} &\n${game}" > ${tmpgame}
  echo "starting ${game}"
  xinit ${tmpgame} -- :1 -xf86config xorg-game.conf || exit 1
else
  echo "not a valid argument"
fi
```

Далее делаем скрипт исполняемым и запускаем следующей командой:

```
$ ~/game.sh имя_игры
```